# leaving entity framework entity properties empty when they're not applicable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm afraid that this might be at risk of being closed for being opinion-based but...

I have an entity

```
namespace Rota.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Shift
    {
        [Key]
        public int ShiftID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public string EndTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan ShiftLength {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(EndTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(StartTime));
            }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeShift> EmployeeShifts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

what I was wondering is, whether it is perfectly OK to leave some of the fields intentionally blank, like for examble if a starttime/endtime is not applicable like e.g. if the person is on holiday, which wouldn't require start or end times.

currently my initaliser file looks like this:

```
protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
        {
            List<Shift> shifts = new List<Shift>()
            {
                new Shift { Name = "Early", StartTime = "08:00", EndTime = "16:00" },
                new Shift { Name = "Normal", StartTime = "9:00", EndTime = "17:00" },
                new Shift { Name = "Late", StartTime = "10:00", EndTime = "18:00" },
                new Shift { Name = "Holiday" },
                new Shift { Name = "Sick" }
            };
            shifts.ForEach(s => context.Shift.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
         }
```

it just doesn't feel right keeping these blank, but i also have no idea what i would/could do differently.

**Is it OK to leave entity properties empty when they're not applicable**

Comment: That's common practice. Some fields may be nullable and not required. You do have to be careful with certain types of fields like DateTime and how the empty value is represented in EF vs the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use TimeSpan instead of string, since you can do calculations more easily with the timespans, they can be nullable if you don't want to have values for them. But generally the Holiday or Sickleave should be a "full date" event, so it could be from 00:00 to 24:00. It kinda depends on how you want to model your data and what you are going to do with them.

And to answer the question, yes, you can have null values for entities as long as you do it on intention and will handle them when using the entities. For example you could have a nullable boolean field for some user setting (allow contact by email etc) having it null would mean this was not asked from the user and should be handle as "no", having a value would mean the user actually have saved settings and the value should be used as is.

Answer (score 0):

Names and data types should communicate your intentions clearly to other developers.  Nullable values are great for that purpose because they not only indicate that the underlying field may be null, but they also break type compatibility unless you explicitly access the `Value` property of the nullable.  It forces the developer to think about how null values should be handled.

With that in mind, I would recommend that you change your StartTime and EndTime:

```
public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
```

When possible, avoid using strings to represent data if there's a narrower atomic data type that will suit your needs.  When another developer sees a string, he immediately needs to know several things that are not immediately apparent:

1. What formats are allowed?  For times, are these 24-hour times or 12-hour?  Dates can be ambiguous because you have to worry about varying formats, time zones, etc...
2. Are nulls allowed?  Is an empty string treated differently than a null string? (I hope not)
3. Is there a maximum string length?
4. Has the data already been validated, or might it include garbage user input that cannot be parsed?

Perhaps all of the above has been clearly communicated via documentation or data attributes... but it's still a *lot simpler* to just use a `DateTime?`, even if you don't need the date part.